# How do I make a return type have the same output as a print function?

Tags: java, eclipse, assert

Say I have this snippet of a code:

```
public String toString() {
    for(int i = 0; i<states.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(states[i]+ " "); 
    }
    return " ";     
}
```

This takes values of an array and outputs this onto the console:

```
AL (Alabama) - Population: 4860545 
AK (Alaska) - Population: 741522 
AZ (Arizona) - Population: 6908642
```

The purpose is actually to return instead of print those values so that the function can be checked using the *assertEquals* but when I change the code so that print is replaced by return as such:

```
public String toString() {
    for(int i = 0; i<states.length; i++) {
        return states[i]+ " "; 
    }
    return " ";
}
```

This still fails the assertEquals check and the error is on the for statement which says that when `i` is incremented at `i++` it is "*dead code*"

How do I have it so the return type does the same as what the print statement is doing?

Comment: Note that you could simply write `return String.join(" ", states)` instead of the loop.

Comment: In this case when you write return inside for loop i++ is a dead code as it will never be executed. I think for assert you want to return only specific value. Please elaborate your requirement more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you want to concat these strings and not return the first one?

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<states.length; i++) {
        result.append(states[i]);
        result.append("\n");
        }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a `return` statement in your loop's body, so your loop returns after the first iteration, which makes no sense.

You are supposed to concatenate all the `String`s and return a single `String`:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    for(int i = 0; i<states.length; i++) {
        sb.append(states[i]);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `String` with the values in `states` to return it.

Let's be honest, there is no need for loops and `StringBuilder`. Just using [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method.

> Returns a new String composed of copies of the CharSequence elements joined together with a copy of the specified delimiter.
>   For example,
>
> ```
> String message = String.join("-", "Java", "is", "cool");
> // message returned is: "Java-is-cool"
> ```

You need to separate each values with a new line since your output is using `println`.

```
public String toString(){
     return String.join("\n", states);
}
```

The advantage:

- It works,
- No separator at the end of the `String`.

Answer (score -4):

You can change the return type to String[] and return the array.

```
public String[] toString() {
                return states;

}
```

Or else you can have a string builder

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder strArrBuil= new StringBuilder ();
    for(int a = 0; a<states.length; a++) {
        strArrBuil.append(states[a]+"");

    }
    return strArrBuil.toString();
}
```

Comment: `Object.toString()` is "declared" to return a `String`. You can't overload the method with a different return type.